# Call a var object form another var in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a var:

```
var main= {
    init: function (model) { // model is an object
        test.init();
        main.model = model;
    }
}

var test = {
    init: function () {
       **Solved** my problem is when i loged it, what i actualy did was:
       console.log('result:' + main.model); 
       //and it failed to concrate string with object
    }
}
```

'main.model' is not found.

How can i access an object from 'main' in 'test'?

**Edit**

The actual code calling main.init() is within the cshtml:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))

    main.init(model);
});
```

Comment: That would work if you called `main.init` before `test.init`. The `main.model` property doesn't exist until you assign to it inside `main.init`.

Comment: Well, ofcoure... that's what i did,

Comment: That's what you call time-dependent objects and its sorta antipattern for OOP. You should avoid it if possible.

Comment: @user3770158 - You've just changed the code completely. What do you pass into `main.init` when you call it?

Comment: its an object, c# class

Comment: @user3770158 - I have no idea what you mean now. Post the code you are using to call `main.init`.

Comment: look now, this is the exact code, model is the mvc model

Comment: @user3770158 - Your problem lies in `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))`. I don't know what that does exactly but I assume the end result is the string `"[object Object]"` so that's what you see when you log it.

Comment: nope i found my problem, its much dumber but i have new to js so.. I will edit in a sec

Comment: @user3770158 - Glad you found the problem. If you had posted your *actual* code in the first place we could have spotted that much quicker :)

Comment: I know But I thought its a simple question and i didnt wanted to waste time posting all the code, Didnt think the solution will be something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main.model` is actually undefined. The `main.model` object doesn't exist until you actually invoke the `main.init()` function.

```
var main = {
    init: function () {
        main.model = 'model';
    }
}

var test = {
    init: function () {
       console.log(main.model);
    }
}

main.init()
test.init()
```

**Edit: Same story.**

```
var main= {
    init: function (model) { // model is an object
        main.model = model;
    }
}

var test = {
    init: function () {
       console.log(main.model.foo); //<--- I get [object Object] 
    }
}

main.init({foo:'bar'})
test.init()
```

Comment: Well i forgot to write it in my question, my fault, but ofrouce i have  initialized them as you specified

Comment: If that is your complete code, then it should work. Are you sure `main` and `test` are in the same scope?

Comment: You are right, it works when i use simple string , but in my case its an object, please check my edit

Comment: Then your code should work perfectly. You CAN access the main object from within test, just by referencing it using `main.model`, like you're already doing.

Comment: But as i said i init it with an object. not a string

Comment: Updated the answer to address using objects.

Comment: I got to it now, thanks for the help, look at my edit